# how to create sub partition in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

Now I started to learn partition concept in oracle.some how i'll manage partition now I tried to create sub partition in Oracle. I've got this error

```
SQL Error: ORA-14160: this physical attribute may not be specified for a table subpartition
14160. 00000 -  "this physical attribute may not be specified for a table subpartition"
*Cause:    unexpected option was encountered while parsing physical
           attributes of a table subpartition; TABLESPACE is the only valid
           option
*Action:   remove invalid option(s)
*Comment:  this error could have resulted from omission of a
           terminating (right) parenthesis following the list of
           subpartition descriptions
```

respective code is:

```
create table sub_pat_test(emp_name varchar2(30),job_id varchar2(30),hire_date date)
   partition by range(hire_date) subpartition by list(job_id)(
   partition p1 values less than(to_date('01-01-2003','dd-mm-yyyy'))(
    subpartition sp1 values('HR_REP','PU_MAN'),subpartition sp11 values(default)),

   partition p2 values less than(to_date('01-01-2004','dd-mm-yyyy'))(
    subpartition sp2 values('AC_ACCOUNT','FI_ACCOUNT') 
    subpartition sp22 values(default)
   )
    partition p3 values less than(to_date('01-01-2005','dd-mm-yyyy'))(
    subpartition sp3 values('SH_CLERK','ST_CLERK')
    subpartition sp33 values(default)
   ))
   partition p4 values less than(to_date('01-01-2006','dd-mm-yyyy'))(
    subpartition sp4 values('SA_MAN','PU_MAN')
    subpartition sp44 values(default)
   )
   partition p5 values less than(maxvalues)(
    subpartition sp5 values(default)
   )) ;
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors - missing commas and you have referred to `MAXVALUE` as `maxvalues`

```
create table sub_pat_test(emp_name varchar2(30),job_id varchar2(30),hire_date date)
   partition by range(hire_date) 
   subpartition by list(job_id)(
   Partition P1 Values Less Than(To_Date('01-01-2003','dd-mm-yyyy'))
   (
    Subpartition Sp1 Values('HR_REP','PU_MAN'),
    Subpartition Sp11 Values(Default)
    ),
   Partition P2 Values Less Than(To_Date('01-01-2004','dd-mm-yyyy'))
   (
    subpartition sp2 values('AC_ACCOUNT','FI_ACCOUNT') ,
    Subpartition Sp22 Values(Default)
   ),
    Partition P3 Values Less Than(To_Date('01-01-2005','dd-mm-yyyy'))
    (
    subpartition sp3 values('SH_CLERK','ST_CLERK'),
    subpartition sp33 values(default)
   ),
   Partition P4 Values Less Than(To_Date('01-01-2006','dd-mm-yyyy'))(
    subpartition sp4 values('SA_MAN','PU_MAN'),
    subpartition sp44 values(default)
   ),
   partition p5 values less than(maxvalue)(
    subpartition sp5 values(default)
   )) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Missed commas between subpartition/partition definitions.

Comment: ya dude when i add comma i've got this error:SQL Error: ORA-14019: partition bound element must be one of: string, datetime or interval literal, number, or MAXVALUE
14019. 00000 -  "partition bound element must be one of: string, datetime or interval literal, number, or MAXVALUE"
*Cause:    Partition bound list contained an element of invalid type
           (i.e. not a number, non-empty string, datetime or interval literal,
           or MAXVALUE)
*Action:   Ensure that all elements of partition bound list are of valid type

Comment: You're getting this error, since you have referred to MAXVALUE as maxvalues. You have added an `s`. See, the answer I have posted here

Answer (score 0):

Try This Working code..

**Partition by date keeping weekly
and sub partition by station name alphabetically for huge records in separate sub partition.**

```
PARTITION BY RANGE (CREATED_DATE) INTERVAL (numtodsinterval(7, 'DAY')) 
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE(STATION)
    SUBPARTITION TEMPLATE (
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_A VALUES LESS THAN ('B%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_B VALUES LESS THAN ('C%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_C VALUES LESS THAN ('D%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_D VALUES LESS THAN ('E%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_E VALUES LESS THAN ('F%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_F VALUES LESS THAN ('G%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_G VALUES LESS THAN ('H%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_H VALUES LESS THAN ('I%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_I VALUES LESS THAN ('J%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_J VALUES LESS THAN ('K%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_K VALUES LESS THAN ('L%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_L VALUES LESS THAN ('M%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_M VALUES LESS THAN ('N%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_N VALUES LESS THAN ('O%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_O VALUES LESS THAN ('P%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_P VALUES LESS THAN ('Q%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_Q VALUES LESS THAN ('R%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_R VALUES LESS THAN ('S%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_S VALUES LESS THAN ('T%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_T VALUES LESS THAN ('U%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_U VALUES LESS THAN ('V%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_V VALUES LESS THAN ('W%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_W VALUES LESS THAN ('X%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_X VALUES LESS THAN ('Y%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_Y VALUES LESS THAN ('Z%'),
        SUBPARTITION SUB_PART_Z_0_9 VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
        )   
(
PARTITION OLD_PART_DATA VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-AUG-2018', 'dd-mon-yyyy'))
);
```

*This will automatically create partitions on basis of created date record entered into table.*